# Impossible to make a new build: "admob.plus.core.Ad$1 is defined multiple times"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, admob, capacitor

*Note: this question/problem is regarding some Android build process, rather than a technical question about AdMob Plus itself.*

I added AdMob Plus to my project, and well, at start, it was working. I have in my phone a working version of my ionic app, built with the --prod flag, that is showing the placeholder ad.

But after having some serious issues trying to sign the APK for the Play Store, I just started being unable to do absolutely anything with my project. I keep having this error regarding AdMob which I'm not able to solve:

```
Type admob.plus.core.Ad$1 is defined multiple times: C:\Zerok\Dev\Proyectos\Dromous\node_modules\@admob-plus\capacitor\android\build\.transforms\caf89848ec3f4a75afca2ab1d3cbcd43\transformed\classes\classes.dex, C:\Zerok\Dev\Proyectos\Dromous\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\build\.transforms\031de8c5ab4ccc04dd0cc8127e017c43\transformed\classes\classes.dex
```

This is the output of the AdMob Doctor:

> ✖ googleads.g.doubleclick.net › RequestError: getaddrinfo ENOENT
> googleads.g.doubleclick.net  ✔ package.json  ✔
> cordova.plugins.admob-plus-cordova.APP_ID_ANDROID ↓ Cordova Android
> dependencies [SKIPPED] ❯ config.xml  ✖
> platform[name="ios"]/preference[name="SwiftVersion"]: Error:
> platform[name="ios"]/preference[name="SwiftVersion"]: missing /
> invalid  ✖ platform[name="ios"]/preference[name="deployment-target"]:
> Error: platform[name="ios"]/preference[name="deployment-target"]:
> missing / invalid ↓ platforms/ios/*.xcodeproj [SKIPPED]  ✔
> plugins/admob-plus-cordova/package.json  ✔ admob-plus-cordova: 1.20.1

I tried following this stackoverflow question, but I don't see anything that has any impact on my project. The AdMob plugin is added just once, aswell the NPM library for the client code.

The other weird thing, is that you'd expect Gradle to care about the files in the /android folder, and not about the ones in node_modules. Why is it having a class collission with a file that's located outside the android folder? This doesn't make any sense.

I can't either build or do anything with my project as for now. I tried updating Android Studio, Gradle, cleaning and rebuilding the project, removing the Android folder and creating it again... and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved after a while! If you're using Ionic with Capacitor, and using some Cordova plugins, then you might bump into this very same problem.

The problem lies in the installation of the AdMob Plus plugin, but may happen when installing other plugins that have implementations both in Capacitor and Cordova. I'm still not sure what caused this, but somehow, installing the plugin for Capacitor, also added the plugin in the "capacitor-cordova-android-plugins" folder. This folder holds Cordova plugins for using them in Capacitor — that's how they get that compatibility with Cordova.

---

So, how does this apply to the error? Let's see it again:

`Type admob.plus.core.Ad$1 is defined multiple times: C:\Zerok\Dev\Proyectos\myapp\node_modules\@admob-plus\capacitor\android\build\.transforms\caf89848ec3f4a75afca2ab1d3cbcd43\transformed\classes\classes.dex, C:\Zerok\Dev\Proyectos\myapp\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\build\.transforms\031de8c5ab4ccc04dd0cc8127e017c43\transformed\classes\classes.dex`

The class `Ad$1` is being defined in two places. The first one is the legit one: it comes from a straightforward Capacitor-installed plugin. The second one, though, comes from that compatibility folder I mentioned earlier, `capacitor-cordova-android-plugins`.

When we enter that folder, and get into `src/main/java`, we can see classes for all the plugins that we're using in our Ionic app. In my case, this is what I could see:

[image]

Inside the `com`, `cordova` and `org` folders, I could find the classes needed for my Cordova plugins for which I didn't have a full Capacitor alternative. But AdMob Plus, which had, **is also there.**

Well, it shouldn't. Just remove the `admob` folder (or in your case, the double-defined plugin that is troubling you), and the app will begin to compile again.